# How to record multiple days worth of video without interrruption

Tags: video

I'm working on breaking a world record for continuous game play, multiple days, with my brother and tried to use my MBP to record it all but Quicktime kept stopping.

**Questions:** Does someone have a better solution for continuously recording that video file?
Does someone have suggestions for how I should/can easily edit that ginormous file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with recording video while also playing is that you are forced to split processing time between video compression and the game.  Your best bet for this kind of extended recording is a real-time encoder that can take the load off the CPU, however such devices are not particularly cheap.  Devices such as the BlackMagic Intensity and Matrox MX02 will perform such a real time encoding task, however they cost $200 to $500.

For best results, I would suggest outputting to an HDMI splitter and using a completely separate computer for recording with the capture interface installed on the secondary computer.  This should also greatly reduce the space required since real time encoding hardware will provide a much higher degree of compression than real time CPU only encoding.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned that we are playing on xbox, i just need regular video recording for a long time and i used quicktime with my webcam

Comment: Ah, the same principal still applies though.  Computer recording of a video without encoding hardware is going to be big.  CPU based encoding has a hard time making good compression in real time and it is almost certainly going to run in to issues if you try doing it for days at a time not to mention the enormous size of the footage.  If you want a cheaper option, you may want to consider time lapse photography and have a camera take a photo once every few seconds.